# Fazer uma consulta livre usando o entity frame MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de trazer um resultado de um cálculo de dias usando **mvc** com **frame entity**.

Minha consulta seria essa :

```
select
   Notas_IdSoft, Notas_TipoLic, t.Notas_Validade,
   DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), t.Notas_Validade ) as Data
from Notas as t   
where
DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), t.Notas_Validade ) >10
```

Gostaria de aplicar ela na minha página, mas não sei como faço isso.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode criar uma classe específica que fara isso para vc:

```
public static class UteisDB
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> CollectionFromSql(this DbContext dbContext, string Sql)
    {
        using (var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = Sql;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    var dataRow = GetDataRow(dataReader);
                    yield return dataRow;

                }
            }


        }
    }

    private static dynamic GetDataRow(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dataReader)
    {
        var dataRow = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
        for (var fieldCount = 0; fieldCount < dataReader.FieldCount; fieldCount++)
            dataRow.Add(dataReader.GetName(fieldCount), dataReader[fieldCount]);
        return dataRow;
    }
}
```

Depois é consumir esta classe assim:

```
SQL = "select count(*) as Qtd from minhaTabela";
var MyList1 = db.CollectionFromSql(SQL).ToList();
```

É isso.